# Main extends scala.App is not working after upgraded to scala 2.11.0 to 2.12.0

Tags: scala

I used the below code snippet (in scala-2.11.8) to make object as executable program. But when I migrated the scala version 2.12.0 it is not working. It is throwing error to implement some of the deprecated methods.

```
object Main extends App {
   Console.println("Hello World ")
}
```

as there were a change in delayedInit method, How would I proceed to make my object as executable using App trait.

Q : How to make my object as executable in scala 2.12.0

Update : Facing this issue when Using Idea 14 with scala plugin
Working fine with scala REPL terminal

Comment: @Jwvh - i referred this link. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.0/scala/App.html

Comment: I only suggest removing the `Console` part because it's not needed. Your code compiles and runs fine for me with or without it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your snippet?

One behavior change is that it doesn't run as a script under 2.11 but does run under 2.12.

```
$ scala -nc ran.scala
Hello World 
$ scala211 -nc ran.scala
$ cat ran.scala

object Main extends App {
  Console.println("Hello World ")
}
```

Since that is the opposite of what you report, you're doing something totally different.

Comment: Thanks som. I am using Idea IDE. Error screen shot [2.12](http://oi63.tinypic.com/r01e2b.jpg), [2.11](http://oi64.tinypic.com/bx2zk.jpg) As per your terminal style I tried and it is working fine. As there are more method depreciation in 2.12 scala.App, I tagged it with scala.

Comment: @RanjithRajD thanks for the tinypic. I don't understand their "images you would also enjoy." Why would I enjoy those images? Anyway, I don't use IntelliJ but I'll download it again just to check out your issue. `public long executionStart();` is defined under both 2.11 and 2.12 so something else is going on. :)

Comment: I have the same problem using IntelliJ Idea and 2.12, it complains that App must have its methods implemented but it compiles fine in the command line. I removed the `extends App` and added a `main` method and it works fine in the command line and Idea now. A bug in Idea maybe?

Comment: How the `scala` tool works as a runner isn't fully documented or specified. There's an intro example http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html which shows "manually" invoking main; and there's an old man page which also doesn't address how scripted code is run. It's similar to the way unit test runners obey varying and conflicting conventions about what to run and how to run it.